# should be very simple but somehow it's not

Tags: c#

this is kind of a specific situation to a problem the problem is it supposed to produce 0 when numen/domin =1
domin output shows 6 but the result shows NaN

when numen = 4 and domin = sqrt of 4 to the power of 2 which leads to 4/4 it shows the right answer same with all positive integers like 9,16,25,36
but if i put 6 it gives NaN

if I put 7 it shows 1.490116E-08

if I put 8 it shows 2.107342E-08

i know can state

if(numen==domin)
result = 0;

but i really want to know why this is not working properly

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ps
{
    class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
           double numen = 6;
           double domin = Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(6), 2);
           Console.WriteLine(domin);
           double result = Math.Acos(numen /(domin));
           Console.WriteLine(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Read [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: `Sqrt(6)` isn't an integer. So, there are good odds that `Math.Pow(Math.Sqrt(6), 2);` will give an approximation instead of `1` (in that case, `5.999999999999999`). Then, `6/5.999999999999999` will be slightly higher than 1. Use `decimal` instead

Comment: thank u for help!! i understand why it's not working

Answer (score 1):

Well it's basic maths here...

Values of `sinus` and `cosinus` mathematical values vary between -1 and 1, so domain of inverse functions, such as `arcus sinus` and `arcus cosinus` is range between `-1` and `1`.

In your example, `numen/domin` turns out to be `1.0000000000000002` due to rounding errors in `Math` lib. So when you invoke `Math.Acos` which is `arcus cosinus` `domin` is OUTSIDE of function domain, so value returned is `NaN`.

Comment: "1.0000000000000002 due to rounding errors in Math lib"
i am aware of the range of the arcos just didn't know about that the math library has rounding error didn't expect it to be honest my question wasn't around when it's NaN it was around why it's NaN

Comment: @user13674310 So, the reason is rounding errors, which caused value to be outside domain of arcus cosinus, which in turn, caused `NaN` value. If my answer has helped you, you should accept it (green check mark on the left).